# Server Actions and files

Tags: next.js, multipartform-data, serverless

I just want to know is it possible to upload files using server actions to the nextjs project's some folder maybe public folder like storing images, docs, sheets and pdf stuff.

In nodejs we have multer and formidable but I am stuck with server actions because it doesn't use

```
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data
```

I need to store applicants like name, email, phone and resume. I want to know is it possible with server actions.

```
"use server";
import prisma from "@/utils/prisma";
import fs from "fs";
import FormData from "form-data";
import path from "path";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

const uploadApplicant = async (
  name: string,
  email: string,
  tel: string,
  file: File | null
) => {
  const fileName = uuid();
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("file", file);
  console.log("Form data: ", formData);
  const binaryData = formData.getBuffer();

  console.log("Binary: ");
  console.log(binaryData);

  const filePath = path.join(
    __dirname,
    "../../../../",
    "public",
    "uploads",
    `${fileName}.pdf`
  );

  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, binaryData, "binary");

  await prisma.applicant.create({
    data: {
      name,
      tel,
      email,
      fileName,
    },
  });
};

export default uploadApplicant;
```

Comment: I haven't succeeded yet, the context is a little different, because I simply want to continue proxying to a non-public API. You must use serverActiont, otherwise error messages cannot be decoded in production mode. With Fetch, if I enter 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' in the header, nothing happens, if I remove it, it's fine, but I can't send files. This is a bit childish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to grab the `File` object from the binary `FormData` instance that get passed to the server action. Try this:

```
'use server';

import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises';
import { join } from 'path';

export async function upload(data: FormData) {
  const file: File | null = data.get('file') as unknown as File;

  if (!file) throw new Error('No file uploaded');

  const bytes = await file.arrayBuffer();
  const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes);

  const path = join(process.cwd(), file.name);
  await writeFile(path, buffer);

  console.log(`open ${path} to see the uploaded file`);

  return { success: true };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

File objects are a web API that are only available in the browser environment, not in Node.js.

When you need to upload files to your server, you typically don't send the entire File object to the server. Instead, you would send the file data as a binary stream(array buffer). This is usually done using a FormData object, which can handle file uploads. or you should handle the file upload on the client-side.